# Альтернатива html для хранения статей в базе данных

Tags: html, mysql, markdown

Разметка html довольно хороша в плане читаемости/наглядности, но вот с компактностью у нее не очень. Порой теги занимают до 50% содержимого в оформленной статье. Как по мне это перебор. Думал для хранения в базе использовать гораздо более компактный Markdown, но быстро понял, что он не может в полной мере покрыть все потребности в разметке. Может подкинете идейку, в каком направлении стоит копать. Просадки при перегоне html в "что либо" и обратно, не особо напрягают, ибо все равно, все кешируется. Было бы круто найти что то подобное системе xaml/baml из WPF.

Comment: Выбор-то не особо велик: xml/html, markdown, TeX... Да и от предметной области статей зависит.